# ProgressBar not changeable by user

Tags: android, progress-bar

How can I make a ProgressBar in Android not changeable by user.
I don't mean 'disabled', since my application will update it dynamically. 
I would like the ProgressBar to update by my application but user can't move the bar in the Progress bar to change value?

Comment: I've never seen a progress bar that is modifiable by the user. They are always only modified through the program. Are you sure you don't have the wrong control? I haven't messed with Android, but if their default ProgressBar truly is user modifiable, I'd be surprised, not to mention a little scared of moving to Android.

Answer (score 3):

Check your layout xml and code to make sure that you are using the ProgressBar widget and **NOT the SeekBar widget.**

SeekBar looks like the Progress bar but is user modifiable.

Have a look at [this ProgressBar example](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ProgressBar1.html) from the ApiDemos for reference.